# Sefardim don't ever listen to live music?

Tags: halacha, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, music

Someone speaking casually mentioned to me that Sefardim don't listen to live music at all at any time of the year, but will listen to recorded music because "that's not music."

Is this true? Is this brought down anywhere in *halacha*?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16824/discussion-on-question-by-shokhet-sefardim-dont-ever-listen-to-live-music).

Comment: I know Sfardim who do listen to live music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kisur Yalkut Yosef Siman 651, Rabbi Yishak Yosef discusses the laws of music.
Recorded religious music (which doesn't include indecency or kalut rosh), even with instruments, you can be mekil to listen to it.
However, ANY type of live music is forbidden, unless at a seudat misvah/holiday.
You are allowed to listen to acappella, as long as there is no kalut rosh.

Comment: +1, thanks for the answer....part of my question was if Sefardim keep this; as R' Moshe Feinstein also said that music should not be listened to, but I don't know any Ashkenazim that are מקפיד on that....I don't either know any Sefardim who are מקפיד on this, but I don't know that many Sefardim

Comment: As with many laws, such as Rabbi Ovadia Yosef's ruling on TV (nothing worse), even people who say they follow him for everything commit these "Issurim". It depends where you are on the Spectrum.